# How to pass a function and its arguments through a wrapper function in R? Similar to *args and *kwargs in python

Tags: python, r, argument-passing

I want to write a wrapper function in R. I should take a function and its arguments. Do something, and then call the function with the supplied arguments.

I know how to do it in python, but I search for an implementation in R.
In python I would write:

```
def wrapper(func, *args, **kwargs):
    #do something here
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
wrapper <- function(func, ...) {
    func(...)
}
```